# Apache2 Range upload (PUT) HTTP 204 No content

Tags: apache, header, range, webdav, put

I have Apache 2.4.7 over Ubuntu and trying to upload files partitioned with "Range x-x" header.

`mod_dav` and `mod_headers` are enabled. Also the webdav directory has the "Header Content range bytes" enabled for PUT ranged requests.

I don't know if I should do any more configuration but when I do subsequent range PUT, this is what I get:

```
PUT /webdav/header4/header4_201_1400000.ismv HTTP/1.1\r\n
Range: bytes=0-667\r\n
Content-Length: 667\r\n

HTTP/1.1 201 Created\r\n
Location: http://10.168.200.94/webdav/header4/header4_201_1400000.ismv\r\n
Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n
Content-Length: 71\r\n

PUT /webdav/header4/header4_201_1400000.ismv HTTP/1.1\r\n
Range: bytes=667-4498\r\n
Content-Length: 3831\r\n

HTTP/1.1 204 No Content\r\n
Content-Length: 0\r\n
```

I get the `204 No Content` as if the file was being overwritten but not appended.

Comment: Note that even though Apache _may_ support this, it is explicitly forbidden by the HTTP specification, and generally considered a 'bad idea'. So only do this if you know you'll only ever target an apache server you control.